# Selecting rows based on multiple column values in pandas dataframe MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame MultiIndex:

```
f1  f2  value
2   2   4
2   3   5
3   3   4
4   1   3
4   4   3
```

I would like to have an output where f1 == f2:

```
f1  f2  value
2   2   4
3   3   4
4   4   3
```

Can you suggest an elegant way to select those rows?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) if `f1`, `f2` are columns:

```
df = df[df.f1 == df.f2]
print (df)
   f1  f2  value
0   2   2      4
2   3   3      4
4   4   4      3
```

If level of `MultiIndex` are `f1, f2` use [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
df = df[df.index.get_level_values('f1') == df.index.get_level_values('f2')]
```

Or if `f1`, `f2` are columns names or levels of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.query('f1 == f2')
print (df)
   f1  f2  value
0   2   2      4
2   3   3      4
4   4   4      3
```

Comment: Thank you  df = df[df.index.get_level_values('f1') == dfdf.index.get_level_values('f2')]
worked